# Is there a SQL query that returns client IP?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ip

I'm wondering if there is a SQL query that would show the IP of the client that wrote the query. Like if I have people making changes to my database I already have a log table but I want to add IP address to it. So I am wondering if this this possible.

Comment: Not unless the IP address is stored in the database.  Do you understand how SQL queries work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142142/sql-query-to-get-servers-ip-address ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941074/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-from-sql-server-2008-itself

Comment: If it's an interactive session then it probably makes sense to speak in terms of "the client that wrote the query." I think you mean "submitted the query" or "executed the query". Unfortunately too many people are ready to pounce on confusing language.

Comment: figured this wasn't possible but had to ask. I am relatively new to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If the connection was made with TCP, the query below will return the client IP address.  Note that `VIEW SERVER STATE` permissions are required with this method.

```
SELECT client_net_address
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
WHERE 
    session_id = @@SPID
    AND net_transport = 'TCP';
```